# Is there a problem with my conditional, or how I'm using remove()?

Tags: python

Simply trying to remove every other element from a list.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in lst:
    if lst.index(i) % 2 != 0:
        lst.remove(i)

print(lst)
```

Expected to receive: [1,3,5]

Actually received: [1,3,4]

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't modify a list that you're iterating over.

Comment: After you remove an element, the indexes of all the following elements changes. So the odd elements become even and vice versa.

Comment: Are the list elements guaranteed to be unique? If not, using `index()` and `remove()` won't work because they look for the first occurrence, not the current element in the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are iterating over the list but at the same time you are removing elements from it, so you end up messing with your indices.

May I suggest a pythonic alternative, which instead of directly removing elements from the list (hence, mutating it), we create a new one with the appropriate values filtered out:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# Filter out values using list comprehension
lst = [e for ix, e in enumerate(lst) if ix % 2 == 0]

print(lst)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list while iterating over it. One way to solve it is to first create a copy of the list and then delete the items from this using the indices of the untouched original list.

If you insist of using your method to solve the problem, then in the example below you don't iterate over the list but over the indices generated by a `range` function. You then use the original lists items `lst[i]` which is not modified in your for loop. If you are open to suggestions, you can also use NumPy. For this small example, it will be an overkill though

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst_copy = lst.copy()

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        lst_copy.remove(lst[i])

print(lst_copy)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify a list that you're iterating over with `for in`. And when you remove an element, the indexes of all following elements is decremented.

You can solve these problems by iterating over indexes, and working your way from the end rather than the beginning:

```
for i in range(len(lst)-1, 0, -1):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        del lst[i]
```

You could also get rid of the `if` in the loop by getting the last odd index, and then using a step of `-2`.

```
if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
    end = len(lst)-1
else:
    end = len(lst)-2
for i in range(end, 0, -2):
    del lst[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `filter` and `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

even = lambda _: not _[0] % 2
lst = map(itemgetter(1), filter(even, enumerate(lst)))

print(list(lst))
# [1, 3, 5]
```